# Why are classes not defined symbols in Java, except when you access properties on them?

Tags: java

Consider the simplest possible example. We have

```
public class Foo {}
```

Therefore we can say

```
Foo.class // ==> class Foo
```

It therefore stands to reason that `Foo` should be a `java.lang.Class`, as we clearly have access to it and can manipulate it in the current context. Yet

```
Foo instanceof java.lang.Class
```

raises the error

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:    variable Foo
Foo instanceof java.lang.Class
^-^
```

This isn't anything to do with instanceof itself, though; just

```
Foo
```

alone in the OpenJDK shell produces the same error.

How can we be accessing properties on `Foo` if `Foo` does not exist in the current context?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean, `Foo` is not a **variable** it is a `class`. How could a class be an instance of some type besides `Class`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The `instanceof Object` line was just an example, such as to show that `Foo` doesn't seem to act in a consistent way between `Foo instanceof x` and `Foo.class`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I don't think this is a duplicate - looking there, it's not clear to me why `Foo.class` would get the property on the `java.lang.Class` instance whereas `Foo instanceof x` wouldn't.

Comment: I was thinking in particular of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990369/369). `Foo` is a class. It's not a `java.lang.Class`, it's not an object. It's just a symbol. You can use symbols that refer to classes in different ways than symbols that refer to variables. E.g. `class Bar extends Foo` is valid, but `class Bar extends myObject` is nonsensical. One of the things you can do with a class symbol is get an object (java.lang.Class) that represents the class, which you do with `Foo.class`. So `Foo instanceof x` doesn't make sense, because `Foo` doesn't refer to a variable.

Comment: Also note that `Foo.class` is not really "accessing a property" in the same way as "myObject.getProperty()" is. It's just separate syntax that looks similar.

Comment: `Foo.class` is of type `Class<Foo>`. `Foo` is a class, not an instance of type `Class<T>`. Only its attribute `class` is. And `Foo instanceof x` is not valid Java, as stated above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class name may be used in your source code as a part of many different expressions.  It doesn't mean that the class name itself is an object; it just means that the name itself can be used as part of a bigger expression.  These are not "properties" or attributes; they are other syntactical constructions used to form expressions with many different parts.

The JLS defines how a "TypeName", e.g. `Foo` can be used to form expressions in Chapter 15.  Specifically:

- [Section 15.8.2, Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

  > *TypeName* {[ ]} . `class`
- [Section 15.8.4, Qualified this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4), to access the lexically enclosing class.

  > *TypeName* . `this`
- [Section 15.11, Field Access Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11), to access the lexically enclosing class as a superclass.

  > *TypeName* . `super` . *Identifier*
- [Section 15.12, Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), to call a static method.

  > *TypeName* . [*TypeArguments*] *Identifier* ( [*ArgumentList*] )
  >
  > *TypeName* . `super` . [*TypeArguments*] *Identifier* ( [*ArgumentList*] )
- [Section 15.13, Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), to refer to methods of an enclosing class that may be invoked later.

  > TypeName . `super` :: [TypeArguments] Identifier

It may also be a "Reference Type" eligible for other expressions, such as:

- [Section 15.16, Cast Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16), to create cast expressions.

  > ( *ReferenceType* {*AdditionalBound*} ) *UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus*
- [Section 15.20.2, Type Comparison Operator `instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2), using `instanceof`.

  > *RelationalExpression* `instanceof` *ReferenceType*

There are specific uses of a type name e.g. `Foo` that are described above.  This does not imply that the type name can be used generally as its own object.  Type names are allowed only as part of larger expressions that can be otherwise unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. So effectively types are defined as a special case, and do 'just work that way'.

Answer (score 3):

`Foo` is a ***type***. `Foo.class` is an ***object*** that represents a type.

The `instanceof` operator takes an object as its first argument and a type as its second argument. `Foo` doesn't work as a first argument because it isn't an object- it's a type.

As for why you can do `Foo.class`... well, that's just the way Java syntax works. The structure of the class itself is known during runtime and is represented by a `Class` object which is shared by all instances of that class. The `.class` syntax is one way of accessing that object.

Comment: Thanks. That'd make sense, were it giving some kind of error about an invalid type being presented to `instanceof` - but it's not, it's saying there's literally nothing called `Foo` in scope. Even just typing `Foo` and hitting Enter in an OpenJDK shell produces that response.

Comment: Note that your error says that it can't find a symbol that matches "variable Foo". This makes sense, because Foo is not a variable.

Comment: So why do you not get an error about a missing variable `Foo` when doing `.class`?

Comment: Because a class name followed by `.class` is valid syntax. It's not looking for a variable, it requires a class.

Comment: So effectively `.class` on a type is just "that's the way it is", then - it's reading it and looking specifically for that and nothing else? That seems... very odd.

Comment: @CurtisParfitt-Ford What is odd about it, the syntax of it or what is returned by it?

Comment: The syntax. To me, it seems very strange to be able to do something that looks like accessing a property on something that for all other intents and purposes the language decides does not exist.

Comment: How else would you expect the syntax to look if you wanted to access the `Class` object of a type within a static context?

Comment: "That seems ... very odd" is an expression of bias. "Seems" is a subjective term, meaning "I assess that". The problem here isn't whether Java's long-standing, well-documented syntax is "odd", but whether a person subjectively feels that it is. Such feelings have little to do with engineering assessment.